# tengo problemas tratando de centrar el contenido de una pagina, ademas no logro mover un aside hacia la derecha (HTML y CSS)

Tags: html5, css3, flexbox

Estoy haciendo un curso online de diseño web profesional y en una clase en la cual tuvimos que hacer un layout diseñamos una pagina simple, el problema surgio cuando escribi el codigo de el aside, por algun motivo que no logro entender el mismo no se alinea a la izquierda del body, ya compare enteramente el codigo del profesor y el mio y no encuentro ningun error.
Lo que mas dudas me genera es que al abrir la pagina del profesor tiene el aside bien ubicado.

aqui dejo mi codigo para que lo revisen.
desde ya muchas gracias.

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Layout con Flexbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Estilos.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
         <header>
           <div class="logo">
               <img src="imagenes/logo.png" alt="">
           </div>
         <nav class="menu">
             <a href="#">Inicio</a>
             <a href="#">Blog</a>
             <a href="#">Contacto</a>
        </nav>
     </header>

     <section class="main">
        <article>
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="imagenes/thumb.jpg">
            </div>

            <h2>Titulo del Articulo</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi feugiat nisl et magna vestibulum dignissim. Mauris ultricies ultricies urna, vel mattis libero efficitur at. Cras ac augue nunc. Cras pharetra nec dui quis fringilla. In vitae augue turpis. Praesent ac ornare massa. Ut ut elit urna. Integer dignissim ornare tortor, sit amet placerat sem. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin porta mi vel tempor laoreet. Sed molestie, erat eget tincidunt viverra, est turpis rhoncus lacus, sit amet molestie leo neque eu lectus. Proin tincidunt nisl nec placerat fringilla. Sed in nibh ligula. Pellentesque nec leo consequat, pellentesque enim ac, sodales arcu.</p>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi feugiat nisl et magna vestibulum dignissim. Mauris ultricies ultricies urna, vel mattis libero efficitur at. Cras ac augue nunc. Cras pharetra nec dui quis fringilla. In vitae augue turpis. Praesent ac ornare massa. Ut ut elit urna. Integer dignissim ornare tortor, sit amet placerat sem. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin porta mi vel tempor laoreet. Sed molestie, erat eget tincidunt viverra, est turpis rhoncus lacus, sit amet molestie leo neque eu lectus. Proin tincidunt nisl nec placerat fringilla. Sed in nibh ligula. Pellentesque nec leo consequat, pellentesque enim ac, sodales arcu.</p>
        </article>
     </section>

     <aside>
        <div class="ad">
            <p>AD</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ad">
            <p>AD</p>
        </div>
     </aside>
     
      <footer>
          <div class="autor">
            <p>Creado por Lucio Martinez - EagleLearners</p>
          </div>

          <div class="redes-sociales">
            <a href="https://es-la.facebook.com/ar/">Facebook</a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/">Twitter</a>
          </div>
       </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***CSS***

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    background: #000 url("imagenes/fondo.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.conteneder {
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

header .menu a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 40px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

header .menu a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}

.main {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 70%;
}

.main article .thumb {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.main article .thumb img {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}

.main article h2 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 32px;
}

.main article p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 27px;
}

aside {
    width: 30%;
    background: #537dca;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

aside .ad {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 50px 0;
    background: #4264a2;
}

footer {
    margin-top: 20px ;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

footer .redes-sociales a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

footer .redes-sociales a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    .main {
        width: 100%;
    }

    aside {
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    aside .ad {
        width: 40%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    header {
        flex-direction: column;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    header .menu {
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    header .logo {
        margin-bottom:20px ;
    }

    header .menu a {
        margin: 0 20px;
    }

    footer {
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
    }

    footer .autor {
        order: 2;
    }

    footer .redes-sociales {
        order: 1;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    aside {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre revisa bien tus clases, tu clase es `conteneder` pero lo correcto seria contenedor, esto en los css de tu web, como nota, siempre recomiendo inspeccionar los elementos con F12, de esa forma puedes ver si al elemento se le están aplicando los estilos de forma correcta y encontrar el error mas fácilmente.

Comment: mil gracias, ya lo corregi. Al final me hice la cabeza por un detalle.

Comment: No hay problema, si te sirvió, marca la respuesta como aceptada.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes una clase mal puesta en el CSS

```
.contenedor {
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, ya lo pude solucionar.